# Sitecore SXA XP 10.2 Bucket Items Not Working

Tags: sxa, buckets

Tried creating bucket items with the Page template, with the Page template as a base and without. I get the following error no matter which way I create them.

***"Unbucketable Item stored in an Item Bucket
This item is stored in an item bucket. However, it is not hidden because its template is not bucketable. If you want to hide this item in an item bucket, you must make the template that is based on bucketable."***

I followed https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/custom-bucket-structures.html, [Bucketing rule is not working](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/29059/bucketing-rule-is-not-working) and https://blog.martinmiles.net/post/understanding-buckets-adding-new-items-to-buckets-correctly

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the bucketable checkbox checked in the standard values of your page template?

Comment: Can you show the configuration that you have set on the bucket and bucketable item template?

Comment: @Gatogordo that was it. I set the bucketable on the ribbon, but needed to check that too. Thanks.